# Eclipse syntax colors for HTML files

Tags: eclipse, colors, syntax-highlighting

I'm using eclipse for a few months, I realy like gvim better but eclipse makes my life easier with pydev and phpeclipse. Everything is pretty nice, I have a black fluxbox and black GTK themes, I've changed the syntax colors for py and php and now everything is dark background, light foreground (including the eclipse menu/borders/etc), very nice.

But.. I can't find a way to change the syntax colors for html files. It's really bad, occasionally I will want to open a html file in eclipse and standard text is black (same as my background). I've changed every background-related color setting I could find but the html editor's colors don't change. Am I missing something? Does anyone know how to change this?

Comment: I've been looking for a dark Eclipse color scheme. Maybe you can export/upload your configuration? No one seems to have done that yet (at least I can't find any). Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install the [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) plugin to add all that HTML/JS/CSS support.

I would also recommend using the [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) plugin for all your PHP needs.

After installing these plugins.. you should be able to access their properties in Window>Preferences...

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i have wtp installed but anyway im not getting any colored syntax for my html files. what should i do??

Answer (score 0):

For others who may not be as familiar with the Preferences for Eclipse you can find most of these color settings (once you have the plugins mentioned here installed) at:

Preferences > Text editors > Appearance color options

and

Preferences > Appearance > Colors and Fonts

Don't forget to use the search features built into the Eclipse preference panes to find the exact element you are trying to modify.